# What are the alternative ways of Floodlight Counter tag(in Google Tag Manager)?

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

Here is the Story of current implementation:
I have over 50 Ad Campaigns. To track the user-behavior, I have implemented Floodlight Count tag for all of those. However, it is eating up lot of container size. Therefore, I am looking for a solution with which, I can dynamically fire Floodlights or without implementing Floodlights, I can get the similar result.

I already have implemented [this](https://www.3whitehats.com/knowledge/doubleclick-floodlight-tags-and-google-tag-manager-lean-up-your-containers) solution. However, it increases the Loadtime of the webpage as it contains RegEx table(and my RegEx table has over 50 entries).
I am looking for a solution which involves minimal use of Custom variables by mostly using what is available by-default in GTM.

Answer (score 0):

1. What's available by default in GTM (not counting custom variables) wouldn't be sufficient for covering 50 ad campaigns in an effective manner. You could always create 50 triggers and 50 tags, hardcoding your ids and maintain them separately in different tags, which is quite far from being the best practice. It actually may be the worst practice, especially given how the container size is hard-limited for GTM.
2. Even a large rLUT should be very insignificant given that the variable against which it's executed is reasonably small and the url is most definitely a tiny string. Have you actually measured the page load speed with and without the rLUT? Have you debugged the load speed issues and narrowed them down to the rLUT? It's actually quite an achievement to make GTM significantly affect the page load speed, given how it's all async and non-blocking.
3. You could reimplement the rLUT in a CSJ variable, which may be more preferable if you're good at JS, but it won't improve performance. Just like an rLUT won't hinder performance.